# Mysql, check if all rows of each column have the same value

Tags: mysql

A friend of mine wants to check if all the rows, of each of the columns of a table, have the same value.
If they do, then print the value.
Else just print an empty string or null or something.

Imagine this table for example:

```
+--------+----------+-----+
|  Name  | Lastname | Age |
+--------+----------+-----+
| Peter  | White    | 30  |
| Marry  | Jane     | 30  |
| John   | Doe      | 30  |
+--------+----------+-----+
```

The result of the wanted query would output the following:

```
+--------+----------+-----+
|  Name  | Lastname | Age |
+--------+----------+-----+
|  NULL  |   NULL   | 30  |
+--------+----------+-----+
```

I tried to create a function where I would get the columns of a given table, loop through each column name and execute a query. But since I am not familiar with Mysql I obviously miss something out and I can't figure out how to achieve what I'm trying to do here.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;

DELIMITER //

create procedure test()
begin
    declare i int(11);
    declare col_name varchar(50);
    declare num_rows int(11);
    DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
        SELECT column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name='name_of_my_table' and table_schema='name_of_db'; 

    select FOUND_ROWS() as num_rows;
    set i = 1;
    open col_names;
        the_loop: LOOP

           IF i > num_rows THEN
                CLOSE col_names;
                LEAVE the_loop;
            END IF;

            FETCH col_names 
            INTO col_name;     

            -- Here I would like to perform a query for each column
            select count(*), col_name from name_of_my_table group by col_name;
            -- Then I was thinking of making an if/ else condition to check 
            -- if I get more than 1 result per column, implying that                 
            -- not all rows have the same value for this column.

            SET i = i + 1;  
        END LOOP the_loop;

    CLOSE col_names;
END//

DELIMITER ;

call test;
```

What this outputs is the count and the column name of the last column found, which does make sense.
I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible with Mysql only, I can easily do that in PHP but I am wondering if I can do that with a single query as well.

Comment: Just use `count(distinct column_name) ` on each of the columns and is the count > 1, then return null.

Comment: @Shadow The problem is that it will output the result for the last column fetched only. I want to print the value of the column (if all rows have the same) or a null, for all columns, not just the last one.

Comment: Use an aggregate function (min/max) to get the value in case the count=1.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below query.

`select if(count(distinct(Name))=1,Name,null), if(count(distinct(Lastname))=1,Lastname,null), if(count(distinct(Age))=1,Age,null)
 from your_table;`